# can you hide conflicts in a data view SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-services

Just wondering if its possible to hide the data conflict message and accept all changes without having a user interact with it in a SharePoint list using the data view?

Comment: What conflicts? What message? Imagine we can't see your screen and you need to describe the problem.

Comment: When in the data sheet view in a list if you change a fields value, then change that same field again the box pops up saying there is a conflict because I'm trying to change a field another user has changed. But in reality that other user is me. Can I turn that off so I don't have to tell it to accept my changes every time and just have it accept it when I retype a value again?